# Problem with calling elements in n-dim Arrays Python?

Tags: python

I am new to python. I have an array of the form:

```
Alpha = [[A  B  C]
 [D  E  F]]
[[1  2  3]
 [4  5  6]].
```

This seems to be a 3d array. However when I try to call for a specific element (for e.g. by typing Alpha[1][1][0] - to get 4 as output), it doesn't give any output. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: You must provide a [mcve].

Comment: Fix the syntax.  Add the missing commas, and you're missing an outer pair of square brackets.  It should look like `[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]]`

Comment: _This seems to be a 3d array._ That's not valid Python.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the array syntax for you:

```
>>> alpha = np.array([[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]])
>>> alpha
array([[['a', 'b', 'c'],
        ['d', 'e', 'f']],

       [['1', '2', '3'],
        ['4', '5', '6']]], dtype='<U1')
>>> alpha[1][1][0]
'4'
>>>
```

That element is indeed 4 so something else is wrong.

As said in comments, it would be best to provide a minimal working example in which we can help you fix your mistake.